# Longtable & scalebox

Tags: longtable, scaling

I have a very long table which i decided to make smaller using scalebox (successfully) and also split into two pages using longtable. However, no matter how hard I try, I cannot run those two things together. I am a LaTeX beginner so, please, be patient with me.

Could you please implement longtable to my original table, while still using scalebox? Thanks a lot.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Caption}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}

%tablefill

\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: you can not split `scalebox`. and `table` environment too

Comment: try to change font size `\small` or ...

Comment: try this `\begin{small}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
1&2\\
3&4
\end{tabular}
\end{small}`

Comment: scaling tables is always wrong, it's a good thing it doesn't work with longtable, just use `\small` or `\footnotesize` or whatever size you need.

Comment: @touhami make that an answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please do it

Comment: @touhami But please don't use `\begin{small}`!

Comment: @cfr thank you, usuelly i don't.

Comment: @cfr around a longtable it's not such a bad idea, easier to see the end than a stray `}` several pages later

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess that's true. It just ... looks wrong... even though it works. Irrational, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `\resizebox` for any table, just select a suitable font size such as `\small` or `\footnotesize` so

```
{\small
\begin{longtable}
....
\end{longtable}
}
```

or equivalently

```
\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}
    ....
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
```